# Email Receiving Issue on my Domain Email after Deploying it through Vercel

Tags: email, next.js, vercel

I have built a website on NEXT JS and upload it to my custom domain with the help of Vercel. The website is successfully deployed and up and running. But the issue is that i am not receiving email on my domain email address anymore (using CPANEL). I have also gone through this (https://vercel.com/guides/why-has-email-stopped-working) documentation, but i am unable to understand, as this is my first time experience in uploading a website.

I am willing to provide any information that might help.